# Generating a PDF in Rails with MathJax and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I'm writing a website using Rails 3.2.6 and it needs to be able to display maths formatting on the website. To do this job I am using the mathjax-rails gem which works perfectly rendering the maths on, for example, questions/1. However, I would like the user to be able to download the question containing the maths content as a PDF. I have done a lot of searching and fiddling with my app and the closest I have come to a solution is wkhtmltopdf and the wicked_pdf gem. This works, in that a PDF is created which is saved to the user's computer. However, the maths is not rendered properly because, I presume, mathjax is not actually processing it.

Having done a bit of reading, I thought I found the answer elsewhere where it said to add a delay to the controller to give mathjax a chance to do its magic:

```
format.pdf do
    render :pdf => 'filename',
          :javascript_delay=>5000
  end
```

However this doesn't work either and I end up with a PDF covered in things like:

[itex]3H_{2~(g)} + 2N_{2~(g)} ⇌ NH_{3~(g)}[/itex]

Rather than formatted maths. Has anyone got any clues on how I can get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, any update on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is even a bit silly, but have you tried a longer delay?

With wkhtmltopdf this works:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --javascript-delay 15000 http://www.mathjax.org/demos/mathml-samples/ MML.pdf && MML.pdf
```

This does not work

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --javascript-delay 5000 http://www.mathjax.org/demos/mathml-samples/ MML.pdf && MML.pdf
```

It's the same for the TeX samples as well

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it like this, the only thing is that I used the cdn instead of the gem:

This is my show action in the controller:

```
def show
  @example = Exam.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf: @exam.name,
                  template: "exams/show.pdf.erb", // The template that you want to convert to pdf
                  :javascript_delay=>5000,
                  locals: {:exam => @exam},
                  layout: "application-pdf.html.erb"
    end
  end
end
```

And inside app/views/layouts/application-pdf.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MathTest</title>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" %>
  <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
      jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
      tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
        displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
        processEscapes: true
      },
      "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
    });
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async
          src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

The key is to wrap your pdf template, in my case "exams/show.pdf.erb" in an application layout designed for your pdf, the cdn is loaded in the layout and you just have to give wickedpdf the option to delay the javascript processing so mathjax has enough time to process the page.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

As Peter Krautzberger mentioned, cdn.mathjax.org is shutting down due to budget issues. The solution would stay the same, you just have to load the mathjax from your project internally or use another cdn. You can fiend some cdn alternatives here: https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Comment: Good to know, thank you very much! I guess we will have to download the scripts or use the other cdn, anyway I think the solution will stay pretty much the same

Comment: Right. But maybe you could update the answer so that others reusing it later won't have it fail in the future.